# How can I create a 1000-page pdf faster?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I need to plot more than 1000 pages to a PDF file using `ggplot2` in R. Any faster way to do besides the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
pdf("name.pdf", width = 6, height = 6)
for(i in 1:1000) {
  p1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat,  y = price)) +
        geom_point()
  print(p1)
}
dev.off()
```

My actual case like this;

(1) need to read a file, and create a `data.frame` according to the value for each line of it.

(2) make a plot of each line of that file to pdf.

```
fa <- read.table(file)
pdf(name.pdf, width = 6, height = 4)
for(i in 1:nrow(fa)) {
  new.data <- function(i)
  p1 <- ggplot(new.data,...) + ...
  print(p1)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: You could only call ggplot once outside the loop, and just repeatedly call `print`,  but somehow that wouldn't seem likely to improve a real use-case very much. The plotting functions in ggplot2 are quite slow compared to base and lattice graphics so you might think about a faster plotting paradigm.

Comment: agreed, and: in my experience it's rendering the graph, not constructing it, that takes the time (so probably even for this case moving the `ggplot` outside the loop wouldn't help too much -- but that could be tested by benchmarking)

Comment: move `ggplot` out is not work in my case, different `data frame` will pass to `ggplot()` in each loop. Any other suggestions for my problem?

Comment: As @BondedDust says: how attached are you to ggplot? For this particular example `plot(price~carat,data=diamonds)` (from base R) or `lattice::xyplot(price~carat,data=diamonds)` would both work fine.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, I'm sorry for missing details of my case. In my post just a example. my actual is: for each loop, I need to create a new `data frame`, and then create a plot.

Comment: Since your datasets are independent, and so are you plots,  why not write a multicore version, w/ `mcapply` or `foreach` ?  This may not help if your datasets are large (it takes time to pass to each helper), but might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @Carl Witthoft, I've tried using `foreach` and `parallel`. Computing is much faster, but print out figures is still no so quick. I've added the `code` to my post.

Answer (score 7):

As commented above, speed is one of `ggplot2`'s weaknesses.  It takes some work but you can often replicate the appearance of a ggplot in one of the other standard plotting packages (base or lattice); e.g. [this series of blog posts](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/06/28/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-1/) goes the other way (from lattice to ggplot), but the examples should be helpful. (@G.Grothendieck comments below that `library(latticeExtra); xyplot(y ~ x, diamonds, par.settings = ggplot2like(), lattice.options = ggplot2like.opts())` will generate ggplot-like plots.)

If you were really desperate I suppose you could use `parallel::parApply` to generate a sensible number of separate PDFs and then use external tools such as `pdftk` to stitch them together ...

Set up machinery to generate (approximately) the same plots in all three systems

```
 library("ggplot2")
 library("lattice")
 data(diamonds)
 gg_plot <- function() {
    cat(".")
    print(ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat,  y = price)) +
    geom_point())
 }
 base_plot <- function() {
    cat("+")
    plot(y~x,data=diamonds)
 }
 lattice_plot <- function() {
    cat("/")
    print(xyplot(y~x,data=diamonds))
 }
 wrap <- function(f,npages=20,fn="name.pdf") {
    pdf(fn, width = 6, height = 6) 
    for(i in 1:npages) {
           f()
    }
    dev.off()
    unlink(fn)
 }

 library("rbenchmark")
 benchmark(wrap(gg_plot),wrap(base_plot),wrap(lattice_plot),
           replications=10)
```

OK, this was much slower than I expected (I cut it back to 20 pages per PDF and 10 replications).  (I initially thought `lattice` won by a lot, but that's because I forgot to `print()` the results ...)

lattice and base are both about twice as fast as ggplot ...

```
                test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2    wrap(base_plot)           10  75.693    1.249    74.053    1.596
1      wrap(gg_plot)           10 120.397    1.987   117.507    2.832
3 wrap(lattice_plot)           10  60.590    1.000    58.580    1.976
```

Comment: Note that  `library(latticeExtra); xyplot(y ~ x, diamonds, par.settings = ggplot2like(), lattice.options = ggplot2like.opts())` can be used if its important that it have the look of ggplot2.

Comment: The variables are not consistent in the example... carat-price (ggplot) vs. x-y (base and lattice).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Carl Witthoft's suggestion, I will use `parallel` + `foreach` for my task. Here are examples, I am trying to make simpler plots instead.

Here are my points: Throw the data computing to `parallel` and store the `plots` to a `list` (maybe very huge), at last, `print` all the figures to a PDF file.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("lattice")
data(diamonds)
gg_plot <- function() {
  cat(".")
  for(i in 1:5) {
    fig <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point()
    print(fig)
  }
}

para_plot <- function() {
  cat("+")
  library(foreach)
  library(doParallel)
  library(ggplot2)    
  cl <- makeCluster(2)
  registerDoParallel(cl, cores = 2)
  AllFigs <- list()
  cTime <- system.time(
    AllFigs <- foreach(i = 1:5, .packages = c("ggplot2")) %dopar% {
      fig <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point()
      #fig <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point()
      fig
    }
  )
  stopCluster(cl)    
  print(AllFigs)    
}

wrap <- function(f,npages=20,fn="name.pdf") {
  pdf(fn, width = 6, height = 6) 
  for(i in 1:npages) {
    f()
  }
  dev.off()
  unlink(fn)
}

library("rbenchmark")
benchmark(wrap(gg_plot), wrap(para_plot), replications=10)
```

Yes, I think `parallel` is twice faster than normal. But, I fell it still needs improvement.

```
test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1   wrap(gg_plot)           10 620.109    1.937   611.018    5.125      0.000     0.000
2 wrap(para_plot)           10 320.081    1.000   138.696    5.475      0.349     1.931
```

Comment: When you parallelize across `n` cores or machines the best you can do is an `n`-fold improvement ... maybe this is what you're saying and I've misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, it is. I just want more improvement using `parallel` when using multiple cores. (forgive me not describe my problem more specifically, it's my first post here)